# Show that any complex roots must occur in conjugate pairs.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $p(\lambda)=c_0 + c_1\lambda + \dots + c_n\lambda^n$ be a polynomial with real coefficients. Show that any complex roots of $p(\lambda)=0$ must occur in conjugate pairs, i.e. if $p(\alpha+i\beta)=0$ then $p(\alpha-i\beta)=0$.

So I am kind of having trouble doing this for a general expression. Where should I start? I'd be able to figure it out for some small fixed $n$... Any hints would be helpful

Comment: How are $p(z)$ and $p(\bar{z})$ related?

Comment: Since the coefficients are real, they are the same? For any real number, the conjugate is the same right.. Im confused

Comment: For an arbitrary $z\in\mathbb{C}$. So in general, you don't have $p(z) = p(\overline{z})$, but there is a simple relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You know $\;p(z)=0\;$ , but

$$p(\overline z)=c_1+c_1\overline z+\ldots c_n\overline{z^n}=\overline{c_0}+\overline{c_1z}+\ldots\overline{c_nz^n}=\overline{(c_0+c_1z+\ldots c_nz^n)}=\overline{p(z)}\ldots$$

Comment: The main point of course is that complex conjugation is a ring homomorphism.

Comment: @lhf , you're right but I don't think we even need to mention that. It's enough to prove directly from the definition, just as is many times done at high school level, that $\;\overline{ab}=\overline a\overline b\;$ ,  without even mentioning rings, fields, homomorphisms and stuff.